# How to use value from MAX function in order to determine the next available id?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use a MySQL query to get the latest number from a certain type of measuring instrument (each type of instrument would have their own consecutive numbers starting from value=1), but it returns:

> Error: `SELECT MAX(codigo) AS max_codigo FROM equipos_sgc WHERE
>   tipo='Vernier'`
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: nextCode in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\QMS\Instruments\addsql.php on line 22"

I have tried this code to get and use the result from the max function:

```
/* $result = mysqli_query($sql2);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row["max_codigo"]; */

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sgc");
        if ($conn-> connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed:".$conn-> connect_error);
        }

    $sql2 = "SELECT MAX(code) AS max_code FROM instruments_qms WHERE tipo='$_POST[type]'";
    if ($conn-> query($sql2) === TRUE) {

        $nextCode = query($sql2) + 1;
        echo $nextCode;
    }
    else{
        echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br/>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO instruments_qms (type, instrument, brand, date_last_cal, frequency, date_next_cal, code) VALUES ('$_POST[type]','$_POST[instrument]','$_POST[brand]','$_POST[date_last_cal]','$_POST[frequency]','$_POST[date_next_cal]','$nextCode')";
if ($conn-> query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Added successfully";

    }
    else{
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br/>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
    <form method="get" action="/QMS/Instruments/index.php">
    <button type="submit">Return to Instruments</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>`
```

I expected to get the latest number used from the user input of the type of instrument, but it returned:

> Error: `SELECT MAX(codigo) AS max_codigo FROM equipos_sgc WHERE tipo='Vernier'`
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: nextCode in C:\xampp\htdocs\QMS\Instruments\addsql.php on line 22"

Comment: Your query failed, so you're never setting $nextCode. Try putting your insert query inside of the if statement above it.

Comment: Thank you aynber but I just tried it and didn't work.

Comment: your current method is prone to **race conditions** and your code is prone to SQL injections.. ideally you should use `INSERT INTO .... VALUES((SELECT MAX(code) AS max_code FROM instruments_qms WHERE ...), <other_values>)` and use a transaction instead to solve the race condition..

Comment: `if ($conn-> query($sql2) === TRUE) {` will **fail**. When the query is successful, the result is a `mysqli_result` object. Not a boolean `true`.

Comment: But sidenote: why isn't `code` set up as an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column? Let your database engine handle the incremental number.